# ASP.net Form Auth with MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am writing a website in asp.net with .net 4.0 and using MySQL 6.7.4.0,
I try using MySql as my membership provider for the form authentication.
I added this to membership section in my web.config file:

```
<add name="MySqlMembershipProvider"
     type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider,
           MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
     autogenerateschema="true"
     connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer"
     enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
     enablePasswordReset="true"
     requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
     requiresUniqueEmail="false"
     passwordFormat="Hashed"
     maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
     minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
     minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
     passwordAttemptWindow="10"
     passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
     applicationName="/"/>
```

And when I go to the asp.net Web Site Administration Tool and go to the security tab i get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have added all MySQL dlls to my project refrences, all are in version 6.7.4.0, and all of their paths are correct.

What is the problem?

Comment: Maybe your project has a reference to the MySql.Web assembly but the Site Administration Tool does not. Register MySql.Web assembly into the GAC and try the Site Amin Tool again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the references DLLs are added to your project with a different version of the DLL registered in your GAC. Make sure both are the same version.